# Plot grid over basemap with user input latitude and longitude

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a simple grid over a basemap using my own longitude and latitude data. The only way I know is plotting using

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(geos_lon, geos_lat);
Z = X;
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.5)
```

However, I don't want my grid to be colored which is what pcolormesh is doing. I just want the grid lines. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Simple grid can be plotted with command `plt.gca().grid()`.

Comment: @swatchai How do I use my own data in that command?

Comment: Command `plt.axhline()` and `plt.axvline()` with appropriate parameters will plot horizontal and vertical lines as you need.